# Eclipse Automatically Download / Update JAR files

Tags: eclipse, libraries

I **just created a Web App project** from a repository through Eclipse's SVN support. What I would be doing is have an **ANT build** going and then **finally deploy through Tomcat**.

I am using **Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers** on an **Ubuntu** system.

> There are **a number of jar files needed**
>   to support my project - like **Struts**,
>   **Hibernate**, etc. etc.

Do I need to

> **manually download each of them**
>
> **and put them in the lib folder?**

**OR**

> Does Eclipse have a solution to
>   **automatically UPDATE these from the internet**? **Any plugins** to **automatically** take care of this?

Comment: Although you mention struts, hibernate, this question is not specifically about struts or hibernate (that's just a detail, like the fact that you're using ubuntu) and I removed the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Maven for your project. It's VERY well supported in Eclipse, and handles all dependencies (as well as other things, such as releases).

The problem is there's a bit of a learning curve, but if you intend your project to get to a considerable size, I'd say it's very important.

Maven has support for ant builds and most libraries are in the central Maven repository. You just say your project has a dependency on the external project and it will automatically download the dependencies.

http://maven.apache.org/